# How to get the norm of of the functional?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q},\ r,p,q>0.\ \alpha=(\alpha_{n})\in L^{q}$. Define $T:L^{p}\rightarrow L^{r}$ by $(Tx)(t)=\alpha(t)x(t)$ for every $x\in L^{p}$. Then $\lVert T\rVert=$?

I have done the first part. That is for $x\in L^{p},\ \lVert Tx\rVert_{r}\leq\lVert\alpha\rVert_{q}\lVert x\rVert_{p}$. Then$$\lVert T\rVert=\sup_{x\neq0}\dfrac{\lVert Tx\rVert_{r}}{\lVert x\rVert_{p}}\leq\lVert\alpha\rVert_{q}.$$But I can't choose a specific $x$ such that  $\frac{\lVert Tx\rVert_{r}}{\lVert x\rVert_{p}}=\lVert\alpha\rVert_{q}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried $x=|\alpha|^{\frac{q}{p}}$?

Comment: @PacMafs It really works, thank you very much!